# How to Insert new Entity Class in code first entity framework project without effecting data in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am learning asp.net mvc with entityframework. I start with a dummy project. I am developing a blog for practice. I have a question related to code first EntityFramework. In beginning I create one entity class for the enter user info in my table

here is the class which I created

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCDairy.Models
{
    public class UserDetails
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Place { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I Insert few values in the table. In  my next step I add one more entity class for blog post.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace MVCDairy.Models
{
    public class BlogPost
    {
        [Key]
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public int PostedBy { get; set; }
        public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
        public string BlogDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges in my context class.

```
public class Context:DbContext
{
   public Context()
   {
     Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
   }

   public DbSet<UserDetails> Users {get;set; }
   public DbSet<BlogPost> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

But this initializer delete all the records from my all the table and I have to enter the values again for each table. Is there any good way to insert new entity class that does not effect my table entries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use another Initializer like `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` or you could use `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` (this would not reflect the most recent changes though)

You'll need to pass in a migration configuration in addition to the context.

See [this url on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx) for details on `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`

Answer (score 0):

Enable `Migrations` for your model, you can do it in `Power Manager Console` by following command:

```
PM>Enable-Migrations
```

Note that, you should select the project that contains your `DbContext`.

Every time that you change your model(add or update or delete an entity or change relations or ...)
you can update your database without loosing your data with following commands:

```
PM>Add-Migration  [a name for your migration]
PM>Update-Database
```

If you want to add migration for an existing database then use it with `Ignorechanges` switch:

```
PM>Add-Migration [a name for your migration] -IgnoreChanges
```

You can find more about EF Migrations command at [this link](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/).

After enabling Migration, EF create a `Configuration` class in your project, then you can set your `DbContext` Initializer as following:
You can set your `DbContext` Initializer as:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<BlogContext, 
                                                   Configuration>());
```